# What is the "context of content" in Google's Location Permissions policy?

Tags: google-play, privacy-policy

Our Android app was rejected by Google with the following feedback:

> Please make sure privacy policy is clearly labeled as a privacy policy
> **in the context of the content** and specifies handling of location data.

I do not understand what the *context of the content* is in this case. Does it refer to the in-app link to the privacy policy, or the content of the privacy policy?

Our [privacy policy](https://www.arego.app/privacy-policy/) is clearly titled as such in the document itself. The link to it within the app also reads "Privacy Policy" and is placed in the "About" section of the app, similar to how apps like Tesla and Instagram have implemented it.

Upon asking Google for advice, the response was:

> Unfortunately, I’m not able to provide any more detail or a better
> answer to your question.  As I mentioned in our previous email, the
> "Privacy Policy" is clearly labeled in not only the title but also
> context of content, even translated in English.

Which I can only assume should mean *is clearly labeled only in the title **but not** in the context of content*, as otherwise the app would confirm to their policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the *context* is wherever your feature is implemented in the app. In our case, we had to include a link to the privacy policy directly underneath the switch that enables location services.